# Error when trying to install live server globally

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I try to install live server globally I keep getting this error message even after doing sudo.

```
Password:
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EISDIR: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/nezihdogruer/.npm/_cacache/tmp'
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/nezihdogruer/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/99/f2'

Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/nezihdogruer/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/c3/ca'

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/nezihdogruer/.npm/_logs/2019-12-18T11_26_46_923Z-debug.log
nezihdogruer@Nezihs-MacBook-Pro:~$
```

Any idea what the problem is? Thanks

Comment: what is the version of npm?

Comment: the version is 6.9.0